Trouble Adding OpenAPIGenerator Plugin to Run Build Tool Plug-ins in Xcode Using SPM
I'm using SPM in my project and am trying to integrate Apple/swift-openapi-generator. My project is divided into several modules, for which I'm using SPM. To manage dependencies, I have a Package.swift file.
// swift-tools-version:5.8

import Foundation
import PackageDescription

let openAPIRuntime = Target.Dependency.product(name: "OpenAPIRuntime", package: "swift-openapi-runtime")
let openAPIURLSession = Target.Dependency.product(name: "OpenAPIURLSession", package: "swift-openapi-urlsession")
let openAPIGenerator = Target.PluginUsage.plugin(name: "OpenAPIGenerator", package: "swift-openapi-generator")

let targets: [Target] = [
    .target(
        name: "OpenAPIClient",
        dependencies: [openAPIRuntime, openAPIURLSession],
        plugins: [openAPIGenerator]
    ),
    //...
    ]

let package = Package(
    name: "Modules",
    platforms: [.iOS("16.0"), .macOS(.v11)],
    products: targets.filter { !$0.isTest }.map { .library(name: $0.name, targets: [$0.name]) },
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-generator", from: "0.1.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-runtime", from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-urlsession", from: "1.0.0"),
        //...
    ],
    targets: targets
)

As demonstrated, I've added openAPIRuntime and openAPIURLSession products and the openAPIGenerator plugin to this file. As a result, I'm able to successfully build the project.
Now, I want to add the openAPIGenerator plugin in MyTarget -> Build Phases -> Run Build Tool Plug-ins, but when I press the + button, I can't find openAPIGenerator.

How can I solve this issue?

You probably added a different version of the OpenApi package to your main project as you added within your Package.swift.
As you wrote you added "0.1.0"in your Package.swift file. Make sure you add the same version in your app:

Xcode uses by default this:


I've not added swift-open-api-generator in my main project. I have the local package (OpenApiClient) that contains the config files and it has dependencies to swift-open-api-generator.

If I add here to, build fails saying that config files couldn't be found in target. How can I tell the plugin that config files are in the local package?

You need to add the yaml files in the main target as well. Currently it is not possible to set a different path for the files.
(check around 9:15 in this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10171/)

Is it necessary to add dependency on top level? I'd like to have it only in a local package.

No it is not necessary, just remove the open api dependency from your main app and add you are good to go.
